# Disable Entry Type

Tags: config, entry-type

I dont want to allow people to post from a legacy entry type but I still want the content that was created with that entry type.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `settings > users` you can define permissions for a `group` and/or `user` that determine what entries the user(s) are allowed to view, edit, delete, etc. If you uncheck 'create new entries' then they will no longer be able to post to that section. For more information see the [users documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users).